# assigning non-existent variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, properties, variable-assignment

I've found a line of JavaScript code that I do not clearly understand how it works. Let's say that `window` object didn't have any `app` property set before:

```
var app = window.app || {};
```

The question is - why does JS not throw any ReferenceError for non-existent `app` attribute of `window` object and, instead, it creates `window.app` as `{}` - why? If I execute following line:

```
var a = b || {}
```

I get `ReferenceError: b is not defined` and I'm ok with it. Additionally, I do understand the `xxx || {}` expression - it returns the first element if it's not falsy, and the second one otherwise. It's useful to initialize something undefined with a blank object for example (e.g. default function parameters in JS).

Comment: `Not defined` and `undefined` are two different things in JS `:)`

Comment: "Instead, it creates `window.app` as `undefined`" - where do you see that happening? The code above will create `window.app` as `{}`

Comment: @Ian sorry, you're right, a typo - I've updated my question.

Comment: undefined.anything is an ref error, defined.undefined is just undefined, which is a legit value that doesn't throw in JS.

Comment: With all my love for JS, this seems completely crazy. Is it stated in the docs (ECMA?) somewhere?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz Everywhere: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.1.

Comment: @dandavis I would say that `not-defined` always returns ReferenceError (doesn't have to be `not-defined.anything`) and `defined.not-defined` always returns `undefined`.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: also very true. i was trying to keep it as apples-to-apples as possible, and keep in mind that var a=undefined; alert(a.toLowerCase()) throws on the alert part, not the var part. yes, the error lives "upstream", but you'll most often encounter it when you "reach into" an undefined, like what we see after prepending "window." to a ref which prevents a raw missing ref error on assignment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only get reference errors when trying to use undeclared variables, never for undefined properties.

`||` returns the left hand side if the left hand side is a true value, otherwise it returns the right hand side.

`window.app` is undefined, so it is a false value. It therefore returns the right hand side: `{}`.

The results of evaluating the or statement are then assigned to `app`.

If `app` is a global variable (i.e. isn't declared inside a function), then the property `app` of the `window` object will be created. This is not a consequence of using `window.app` in the test. It is just how global variables work.

Comment: clarification: if you try to actually USE an undefined property, you indeed do get an error...

Comment: No, you don't. If you get the `undefined` value from a property and try to do *certain* things with it, then you'll get an error (but probably not a reference error). The question itself shows that you don't get an error trying to assign that value elsewhere.

Comment: your answer doesn't explain why is `{}` assigned to app... I still don't get it.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: But in your question you state "*I do understand the `xxx || {}` expression - it returns the first element if it's not falsy, and the second one otherwise. It's useful to initialize something undefined with a blank object for example*" What further explanation do you need?

Comment: @Quentin: we're saying the same thing: you as "do" and me as "use". assigning a legit value (undefined) is cool of course, using something that doesn't exist (by reaching down into it further or invoking a method on it) is not cool.

Comment: @dandavis — No, I gave an example of doing/using it in a way that doesn't cause an error.

Comment: Quentin: I missed the fact that I was in the global scope and `var app = ...` is the same as `window.app = ...`. Thank you!